# Switch between database storage and file storage in Python

Tags: python, azure, logging, botframework, azure-bot-service

I want to store my app logs for chatbot made using bot framework in a database through api as well as local file. I am using logger to get the logs for my app.
Also, how to store user email, conversationid, username, user utterance, entity, trace , session id in the log for the azure bot?

Comment: What's the problem? You don't know how to store longs in the file?

Comment: You probably want to use [`logrecord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects) or [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)